Render Shiny plot before tabPanel it is on is selected
A  plot on a specific tab does not start to render until the tab is selected. This happens if it is a static plot as in the code below or a reactive plot where the plot parameters are set in a different tab.
This is an issue if the plots are large or if there are quite a few of them as there is a delay in them appearing once the tab is selected.
Is there a way to tell Shiny to start rendering the plots without waiting for the tab to be selected by the user - so there will be no delay once the tab is selected?
library(shiny)

#how do we get the plots to render 
ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabset",
        tabPanel("panel 1", "this panel will show first"),
        tabPanel("show me the plots",
                 "the plots only start to render once this panel is selected",
                 plotOutput("plot1"),
                 plotOutput("plot2"),
                 plotOutput("plot3"),
                 plotOutput("plot4")
                 )
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(res = 96,{plot(runif(10000),runif(10000))})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(res = 96,{plot(cars)})
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot(res = 96,{plot(runif(100000),runif(100000))})
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot(res = 96,{plot(runif(300000),runif(300000))})
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)

